# How to write TypeScript `get` function for Map object?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do something like this in TypeScript?

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

declare class Map<T> {
  get(name: keyof T): any // ? return type
}
```

Result I need

```
const map = new Map<IPerson>();
map.get("name"); // string
map.get("age"); // number
```

Comment: Your map isn't well-defined. It should be `Map<string, IPerson>`.

Comment: In my example Map is my own class. It's not standard Map class. It can contains only Keys like `keyof T`, and each Value has type defined in incoming object type and depending of Key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the `name` parameter be a generic that extends `keyof T`, and then your return type can use that to index `T` to get the right type. EG:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

declare class MyMap<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K]
}

// Result I need

const map = new MyMap<IPerson>();
map.get("name"); // string
map.get("age"); // number
```

---

P.S. Consider naming your class something other than `Map`, since it will be easily confused with the built-in javascript `Map` object, and will conflict with TypeScript's built-in types for `Map` if present.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does what I need